# Wordpress php add custom post type meta to each post in list from a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type within wordpress called "product_catalogue" where users can add a product's weekly/monthly rental price.

Now on my page that lists all the posts in that post type (i.e. index.php) I am trying to add those prices. The trouble I am having is that my code only allows the prices to be displayed on the first post in the list, and not on all of them.

Here is my code used to add the prices to the products in the loop:

```
function add_prices_to_products() {
    global $post;

    $price_per_day = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_per_day", true); 
    $price_per_week = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_per_week", true); 
    echo '<span class="sl_product_price per_day">£' . $price_per_day . '/day</span>';   
    echo '<span class="sl_product_price per_week">£' . $price_per_week . '/wk</span>';

}

add_action( 'the_post', 'my_custom_loop_start' );

function my_custom_loop_start( $query )
{
    add_filter( 'layers_after_list_post_title', 'add_prices_to_products' );
    add_action( 'loop_end', 'my_custom_loop_end' );
}

function my_custom_loop_end()
{
remove_action( 'layers_after_list_post_title', 'add_prices_to_products' );   
}
```

Comment: U add an action only on "the_post", so the function only echo for the first custom_post.

I'll suggest u to add a function in your index.php, then in your function, loop on the products (https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Then display for each the price.

Comment: Thanks @Nozifel - is there any way to do this from a plugin though, i.e. not altering index.php

Comment: U can do this. Add filter to the content, and push your html at the end of the $content. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: Thanks @Nozifel - do you have a code example you can show me, I don't quite follow you